# Using a control style, how can you bind or trigger a change to ToolTip contents based on ToggleButton.IsChecked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a shared `ToggleButton` style defined that shows one image when `IsChecked` is `true`, and a different image when `IsChecked` is `false`. Binding `IsChecked` to a boolean property on the ViewModel works fine to show the desired image, so I know that my style is being applied and the `DataTrigger` bound to `IsChecked` works.

I would like to change the `ToolTip` text when `IsChecked` changes, but I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting that to work. Ideally I'd like the `ToolTip` to say something like "Turn On" when unchecked and "Turn Off" when checked.

The issue is that the `ToolTip` is not connected to the `ToggleButton` in the visual tree, so I need another way to find the `ToggleButton.IsChecked`. I'm trying to do this entirely in a style, because I've got quite a lot of these buttons scattered around, so no changes to the VMs are permitted.

Ideally the solution would allow me to use the `ToggleButton.Tag` to store the text, and apply a `Converter` and `StringFormat` (or `ContentStringFormat`). I've already overridden the `ContentTemplate` and replaced it with a barebones `ContentPresenter` to get rid of the typical `ToggleButton` effects, so it can be changed further if necessary. (And maybe I've removed something important for this to work? idk.)

Here is my style that works to change image, but the `ToolTip` never changes.

```xml
<!--Toggle button where content is a switch image that's "On" when checked and "Off" when anything else-->
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="OnOffToggleButton" x:Shared="False">
    <!-- this worked to format the initial tooltip contents, but no way to bind.
    <Style.Resources> 
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="Turn on {0}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ???}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="Turn off {0}"/>
                </DataTrigger> 
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources> -->
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ToggleOffImage}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <!-- this works -->
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=Turn on {0}}"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                            <!-- trigger has no effect -->
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=Turn off {0}}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </ContentPresenter.ToolTip>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ToggleOnImage}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- another thing that does not work -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=Turn off {0}}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The buttons themselves are defined similar to this:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource OnOffToggleButton}" 
              IsChecked="{Binding IsPoweredOn, Mode=OneWay}" 
              Command="{Binding TogglePowerCommand}" 
              Tag="Device Power"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringFormat` does not work with a `ToolTip`, as it can contain arbitrary content of type `object`, not just plain text. However, the `ToolTip` exposes a property [`ContentStringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentStringFormat);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that you can use.

> Gets or sets a composite `string` that specifies how to format the `Content` property **if it is displayed as a `string`**.

Since a `ToolTip` is hosted in a separate popup window, it is not part of the same visual tree as the `ToggleButton`, but you can refer to it using the [`PlacementTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the `ToolTip`.

> Gets or sets the `UIElement` relative to which the `ToolTip` is positioned when it opens.

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="OnOffToggleButton" x:Shared="False">
   <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ToggleOffImage}"/>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
   <Setter Property="ToolTip">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ToolTip Content="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                  ContentStringFormat="Turn on {0}">
         </ToolTip>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ToggleOnImage}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ToolTip Content="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                           ContentStringFormat="Turn off {0}">
                  </ToolTip>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

A converter can still be applies in the `Content` binding as usual.

```
<ToolTip Content="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}"
         ContentStringFormat="Turn on {0}">
```

Comment: I was hoping that I could just change the contentstringformat on the tooltip instead of using a whole new tooltip, but this works.